# How to sort mongodb records based on its position in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying MongoDB using Mongoose and getting the record along with populated records, However i would like to sort the populated records i am receiving.

```
const record = Model.findOne({ '_id': '10b9ad30be4c3c0e98cf199q' });
{
  "_id" : 10b9ad30be4c3c0e98cf199q,
  "name" : "Hello World",
  "_order" : [ "28b802cd0588741258d01120", 28b802cd0588741258d01130"", "28b802cd0588741258d01140" ],
}
```

And, After populating It looks like

```
const record = Model.findOne({ '_id': '10b9ad30be4c3c0e98cf199q' }).populate('items');
{
  "_id" : 10b9ad30be4c3c0e98cf199q,
  "name" : "Hello World",
  "_order" : [ "28b802cd0588741258d01120", 28b802cd0588741258d01130"", "28b802cd0588741258d01140" ],
  "items" : [
    { "_id" : 28b802cd0588741258d01140, name: "Games" },
    { "_id" : 28b802cd0588741258d01120, name: "Movies" }
    { "_id" : 28b802cd0588741258d01130, name: "Science?" }
  ]
}
```

How can i effectively sort the populated records `items` based on its `_id` in the `_order` field?
Is it even possible or do i have to do it client side/in server after getting the record.

Comment: I may have a solution to order it by ObjectId (because it is based on time) not as the order it is in the _order array.I believe you can sort by _Id while populating. Is that useful?

Comment: @jackblank it would be pointless if it doesn't match the exact order present in `_order` array, Anyways i can always do it using plain javascript, don't know how performance optimized it would be though.